# Laravel Query Builder - Get table result `as`

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have SQL query to implement in Laravel. My query is :

```
SELECT *  FROM officer_ranks ra
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM officer_rank_details WHERE void = 0) AS r ON  ra.rank = r.present_rank
LEFT JOIN officer_languages l ON r.officer_id = l.officer_id
GROUP BY(ra.rank)
ORDER BY ra.id ASC;
```

To implement this query I wrote:

```
DB::table('officer_ranks as ra')
->leftJoin(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM officer_rank_details WHERE void = 0'), 'ra.rank', '=', 'present_rank')
->leftJoin('officer_languages as l', 'officer_id', '=', 'l.officer_id')
->groupBy('ra.rank')
->get();
```

My question is how do I get `(DB::raw(...))` result table as naming `r` Because I need to `JOIN` tables.

I tried using

```
leftJoin(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM officer_rank_details WHERE void = 0') as r, 'ra.rank', '=', 'present_rank')
```

But it was not succeed.

Comment: `leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM officer_rank_details WHERE void = 0) as r'), 'ra.rank', '=', 'r.present_rank')`. But the original query is not the best way to do that. You should move `void = 0` ito the ON clause. And why do you use `GROUP BY` without any aggregate function?

Comment: I think this will work. I use `SUM()` function to get some count. I did't post that here because it's too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote in the comment how to fix your code. But your original SQL should be:

```
SELECT *  FROM officer_ranks ra
LEFT JOIN officer_rank_details AS r 
    ON  ra.rank = r.present_rank
    AND r.void  = 0
LEFT JOIN officer_languages l ON r.officer_id = l.officer_id
ORDER BY ra.id ASC;
```

In laravel:

```
DB::table('officer_ranks as ra')
    ->leftJoin('officer_rank_details as r', function($join){
       $join->on('ra.rank', '=', 'r.present_rank');
       $join->on('r.void',  '=', 0);
    })
    ->leftJoin('officer_languages as l', 'r.officer_id', '=', 'l.officer_id')
    ->get();
```

I also removed the `GROUP BY` clause, because it doesn't make sense the way you use it.

Comment: Thank you.. As I said I used group by to get `SUM()` in here I just remove that and use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Foxa OK - got it. But I will keep it without `GROUP BY` here, so other people are not confused. You can of course add it in your code again.